# Unity3D Changing Ball Direction When Hitting a Cube

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, physics

I'm working on a simple Paddle Game project nowadays. In the begining, everything's looking good. But, when I complete my level design and publish my game, I see gameobjects in my scene are moving so slow. I think, I pass over the Unity3D's physics limit. If I try some Math instead of Unity3D's Colider, I can finish my first project. (I tried to use [Separating Axis Theorem](http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementation/collision-detection-with-the-separating-axis-theorem/), but I can't handle x and y coordinates on Unity3D.)

I need your help. Thanks a lot for your time. (And If I can handle this problem, I will share my project on the internet, for beginner people like me.)

[image]
[image]

In my project, I achieved this simulation with using BoxColider, but because of Unity3D physics limit, I don't want to use colider in my project.

Comment: Unity's physics engine is pretty fast and the only problems I ran into are situations where objects are moving very fast and collisions were not detected properly. So if you are using the pro version, you should check if pyhsics are really the reason for performancs issues. Maybe there is something else like too many lights, expensive materials (shaders), ...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I find the problem in my project when I read your comment. There are a lot of rigidbody components in my scene. Every objects has got a rigidbody component. I deleted all rigidbody components(because I don't need rigidbody for making basic 2D game) and game works issueless. Thanks. :)

Comment: What do you mean you "can't handle x and y coordinates on Unity3D"? did you get abstracted away from them in such a way that you don't know your position?

Comment: I'm sorry for my English, I just try to say when I write that sentence, I can't control my objects x and y coordinates. For Example : There are two cubes and a script attached first cube. In this script I coded " if(transform.position.x == secondCube.transform.position.x){print("It works")} - I can't see It works message on unity console anyway. And I stop the trying." I hope I can explain myself clearly. Thanks.

Comment: it is possible that because you are using == and comparing two float values, they never reach the same value. try using (pos.x > other.pos.x) and see if you get values out when it crosses the boundary.

Comment: Thanks. My vision is wider than before now. I will try this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't not detect collision.  I'd recommend using Unity's colliders for that, since they're really not bad.  The first thing I notice is that in your first simulation, you have 4 box colliders, when instead you should just have one.  Use the [OnCollisionEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) event (on the spheres) to reflect them off your box.